# dropdown changes depending of text field value

Tags: javascript

I am not very good with javascript and I dont even know if this is possible.

Im trying to get a dropdown to be selected depending on the value of a text field

I have the following text field which is calculated by adding the Number of Adults and Children together.

```
<input type="text" name="Total" id="Total" onfocus="this.blur()"/>
```

What I would like to do is depending on the value of the Total have the following dropdown change .ie  if Total is less than 10 have the dropdown show 1 Hr, between 10 and 20 show 2 Hrs etc

```
<select name="Duration">
<option value="1">1 Hr</option>
<option value="2">2 Hrs</option>
<option value="3">3 Hrs</option>
<option value="4">4 Hrs</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Executing the blur function on focus is confusing. Is it really necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the general direction that you would need to go (I am only including the case where the total is less than 10, so you would need to add the other situations to the if statement):

```
<input type="text" name="Total" id="Total" onfocus="this.blur()" onblur="if(this.value < 10) { document.getElementById('totalDropDown').value = 1; }"/>

<select name="Duration" id="totalDropDown">
    <option value="1">1 Hr</option>
    <option value="2">2 Hrs</option>
    <option value="3">3 Hrs</option>
    <option value="4">4 Hrs</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Hi David,

I'm nearly there with your suggestion

http://jsfiddle.net/4rq3g/3/

The only problem I have is that the dropdown only changes when you click on the Total box, any ideas what will make it change automatically? Its set to show 2Hrs if less than 7 and 4 hrs if greater than 6

Comment: Yes! Sorry, I wasn't sure exactly how everything else was laid out. If you place your 'if' statement inside your 'code' function, then it will be executed each time that a different number of adults or kids is chosen. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

you can look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/knnw8/1/

I would start with

```
<input type="text" name="Total" id="Total" onChange="fillCombobox(this)"/>
```

and then assign the options you want in the combobox as you can see in the fiddle
(you can ofcourse also use onBlur instead of onChange)

edit: I've updated the fiddle a little bit more to your needs

Answer (score 0):

Try this i think this is what you need

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function chkVal(ele){
        var val = ele.value;
        console.log(val);
        if(val < 10){
            $('#totalDropDown').val(1)
        }
        else if(val <= 20){
            $('#totalDropDown').val(2)
        }
        else if(val <= 30){
            $('#totalDropDown').val(3)
        }
        else if(val > 30){
            $('#totalDropDown').val(4)
        }

    }

</script>

<input type="text" onkeyup="chkVal(this)"/>

<select name="Duration" id="totalDropDown">
    <option value="1">1 Hr</option>
    <option value="2">2 Hrs</option>
    <option value="3">3 Hrs</option>
    <option value="4">4 Hrs</option>
</select>
```